# rename cpt in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

Hello i have one cpt which  is case studies but i want to rename it as portfolio .and i have created 10 post under case studies cpt .. so can i rename it cpt ? actually i want change in url .. currently my url is http://www.praxinfo.com/case-studies-page/whatscrackin/  but i want http://www.praxinfo.com/portfolio/whatscrackin/. so how to do this in wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

In your `register_post_type` use the `rewrite` option to change the url but not the actual name of the cpt. This way, you won't run into database problems and your users will still see the new name.

Example from the WordPress codex:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
function create_posttype() {
  register_post_type( 'acme_product',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
          'name' => __( 'Products' ),
          'singular_name' => __( 'Product' )
         ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'products'),
     )
  );
}
```

Here, the url would be `/products/` even though the name of the cpt is `acme_product`.